# Can't get google fonts to work with styles components and ReactJS

Tags: css, reactjs, fonts, styled-components, google-fonts

I have tied everything and I cannot get google fonts to render when using styled components. It always shows the default sans-serif. I have tried to use other google fonts too but have had no success.

In my header.styles.jsx I have:

```
export const Title = styled.div`
  @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Dancing+Script&display=swap');
  font-size: 72px;
  font-family: 'Dancing Script', sans-serif;
`;
```

and here is where I try and use it:

```
import { Title } from './header.styles';

const Header = ({ hidden }) => {
    return (
        <sc.HeaderContainer>
            <sc.LogoContainer to={'/'}>
                <Logo className={'logo'} />
            </sc.LogoContainer>
            <Title>
                My Title Here
            </Title>
            <sc.OptionsContainer style={{ paddingRight: '80px' }}>
                <sc.OptionLink to={'/shop'}>SHOP</sc.OptionLink>
                <sc.OptionLink to={'/contact'}>CONTACT</sc.OptionLink>
                <UserMenu />
                <CartIcon />
            </sc.OptionsContainer>
            {hidden ? null : <CartDropdownContainer />}
        </sc.HeaderContainer>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to set a link tag inside `index.html` to import the font, or following the below:
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/428287/como-utilizar-fontes-customizadas-no-react